# How to extract maximum value from a table in a Database(Sqlite) using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
def maximum(self, conn):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("Select Max(bookId) from Book_database")
    result = c.fetchall()

    if len(result) > 0:
        self.Id = result[0][0]
    else:
        self.Id = 0
    return self.Id


id = maximum(conn)
```

but the id fails when there is no record and also shows that self.Id is a list. How to extract max Id

Comment: Are you using mySQL for this request? I think you have to make it loop through your `result` by using a for loop

Comment: I'm using Sqite3

Comment: You are using `c.fetchall()` which will make the return type a list of sequences, when using `c.fetchone()` you should one get 1 sequence where you can extract the max data with `result[0]` when there is no record in the database the function will return an empty list

Comment: I'm not able to perform transactionId = self.Id +1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'                         
What is the data type returned when there is no record or just a single record

Comment: this means `self.id` was `None` (lhs). is `Book_database` populated?

Comment: @modesitt self. Id fails when the record returns none. How to handle it. I have used c.fetchone()